# what's missing from my JPA entities' OneToMany relationship?

Tags: java, jpa

I'm using IBM RAD 7.5 and WebSphere 7.

I have two entities with a OneToMany relationship (say, Customer and Order).  When I create a Customer with an Order, both entities get persisted correctly.  I have fetch=FetchType.EAGER but when I read the Customer entity it does not contain any of the Orders.

What am I doing wrong?  Here's some code ...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CC_CUSTOMER")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private BigDecimal id;
  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="customer",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Order> orderList;
  public List<Order> getOrderList() { return this.orderList; }
  public void setOrderList(List<Order> orderList) { this.orderList = orderList; }
  /*...*/
}
```

... and ...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CC_ORDER")
public class Order implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="customerid",nullable=false)
  private Customer customer;
  public Customer getCustomer() { return this.customer; }
  public void setCustomer(Customer customer) { this.customer = customer; }
  /*...*/
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Also, here what my DAO looks like...

```
@Stateless
public class CustomerDAO {
  public List<Customer> getAll() {
    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
      Query query = em.createQuery("select c from Customer c");
      customers.addAll(query.getResultLists());
    } finally {
      em.close();
    }
  }
  return customers;
}
```

Any advice or suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks!  Rob

Comment: How are you saving your entities?... by persisting the Order or persisting the Customer?

Comment: I assume you made a type when you were posting your code, in the `getOrderList` method?

Comment: I'm persisting the Customer.  Specifically: 'Customer c = new Customer(); Order o = new Order(); c.getOrderList().add(o); customerDAO.createCustomer(c);'

Comment: And another thing, does it load up a Customer and associated orders when you call `em.findAll(Customer.class)`?

Comment: @Perception I don't see the typo ... what do you mean?

Comment: here's the typo: public Customer getCustomer() { return this.customer; } and public List<Order> getOrderList() { return this.orderList; }

Comment: @Perception I don't have an em.findAll method -- maybe because I'm using Java EE 5?

Comment: @Perception Sorry I don't see the typo/mistake -- that's what I meant to type -- what's the problem you see?  Do you mean just that it's all on one line?

Comment: @RobertHume - ah yes, there's no `findAll()` method on entity manager until JEE6. Did you try joining on Order in your query? Your classes look fine - `select distinct c from Customer c left join fetch c.orderList`;

Comment: the typo is the "return" in both getters

Comment: @Perception Hey!  Your query worked!  Thanks.  I'm surprised I had to manually do the join though, is that normal?  I expected the FetchType.EAGER to take care of that for me?  Please post this as an 'answer', thx

Comment: @johncarl -- ha! did. not. see. that. Thanks! Yeah, that's just a typo (now corrected).

Comment: @RobertHume - Glad it worked. I posted my comment as an answer below - still looking at the spec to figure out why your first try did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class definitions all look fine to me. It would appear that the underlying JPA implementation is not pulling in associated objects via your query. You can pull them in explicitly like this:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("select distinct c from Customer c left join fetch c.orderList");
customers.addAll(query.getResultLists());
```

That will join the customer on all their orders and return the objects properly populated.

Comment: Thanks @Perception, that worked.  For others reading, I'm still not sure why I had to include the "join" part in that query.  Seems like the fetch=FetchType.EAGER should have accomplished the same thing.  Thanks for any other ideas!